# Passing around references in JS inside a function

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I am passing

```
(function(Index){
    Index.Index = function(){console.log(23)};

    Index = function(){console.log(123)};


}(Window.Index = Window.Index || {}));
```

Yet the return I am getting is `Window.Index={Index:function...}`

Which logs 23.

I am -trying- to get it to be re-declared as a function. 
eg expected value should be:

```
Window.Index = function(){console.log(123)};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you get in you function is a reference to the `Index` object, not to the variable containing this reference. In javascript, arguments are always passed by value, even if those values are references in the case of objects.

Solutions would be

**1)** to pass `window` (that is the object holding the `Index` property)

```
(function(holder){
    holder.Index = function(){console.log(123)};
})(window);
```

**2)** to directly change window.Index :

```
(function(){
    window.Index = function(){console.log(123)}; // or omit 'window', that's the same
})();
```

**3)** to pass the name of the property :

```
(function(holder, propname){
    holder[propname] = function(){console.log(123)};
})(window, "Index");
```

**4)** to pass a callback :

```
(function(callback){
    var Index = function(){console.log(123)};
    callback(Index);
})(function(v){window.Index=v});
```

Note that you're basically using the common [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth).

Comment: Correct, I am in actuality trying to implement module pattern to do namespacing etc and ran into trouble trying to namespace a module to a function... ( for backbone )

Comment: In javascript, you don't have pointers to variables. But hopefully the language is dynamic enough so you have many possibilities.